# Screen is super zoomed in after force restart?

Tags: 18.04, display-resolution

I had to force restart my computer after it froze up (I wrote a program that used 100% CPU and RAM). Now, for some reason all the windows on my desktop / the text are super large and everything is blurry due to being way too big.

I'm surprised that a crash could cause my display to get messed up, but it seems like this is the case. This is true on the login screen as well.

I've attached a screenshot below. Hopefully, from this it is easy to tell that everything is blurry / too zoomed in.

[image]

Any debugging tips?

Comment: How did you force restart?  If you used a *safe* restart method (eg. SysRq commands to kernel) I'd not expect issues, if you used *unsafe* methods (eg. power button) I'd suggest system checks starting with `fsck` & what data may have been corrupted via *unsafe* restart.  I'd likely look for files changed about that time...

Comment: @guiverc I used the power button. One question is; how is it possible that my display settings got changed due to file corruption? That's somewhat confusing. Do you think I'm booted into some safe mode thing?

Comment: @guiverc I see there is a "physical volumes: not ok (BAD)" error when I print the system summary. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: If you use a safe restart method (eg REISUB) you can cause your system to safely push cached data to disk & ensure all buffers are cleared (ie. *all data safely stored on disk that needs to be*).  Your power-off decision may have meant some data was still in RAM & didn't get safely written to disk (be it hdd/ssd).. why safe methods should always be used. If you can't recall the commands; pull out your phone & search "magic sysrq" on it & you'll find the wikipedia page & find REISUB pretty easily as it's not a Ubuntu command, but a Linux command and thus would work on ~anything using Linux